# Gulp - Livereload fails for svg inside object tag

Tags: gulp, livereload, gulp-watch, gulp-livereload

My gulp watch task is configured as follows:

```
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts']);         
      gulp.watch('jade/*.jade', ['jade']);      
      gulp.watch('stylus/*.styl', ['stylus'])
      gulp.watch('img/*', ['images']);
    });
```

Everything works like a breeze except for one thing: when updating my svg style, it doesn't come through livereload (i use the gulp-connect plugin), but works when I reload manually... I also noticed that making a change to the .jade file does update the svg style, hence this little workaround :

```
    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['scripts']);         
      gulp.watch('jade/*.jade', ['jade']);      
      gulp.watch('stylus/*.styl', ['stylus', 'jade'])  << workaround to force livereloading the html as well.
      gulp.watch('img/*', ['images']);
});
```

I suspect this has something to do with the object tag that the svg is embedded through but can't be sure. Also the css style is hardcoded in the svg itself using this link :

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"?>
```

I can get it to work through the little hack, but you know, that's not very enlightening as to why this all happens...

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain this to me.